# React Native Android statusbar icons color

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

For an app I develop, I need to change the color icons of the Android status bar (iOS works fine with "default" instead of "light-content") because of the status bar color which is white, but I don't know how to achieve this.

I found this for Android API v23+ but I don't know how to use it in my React Native app:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out how to change the icon colors for React Native. There is, the same way as natively, a `styles.xml` in the `res` folder, where I had to add `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`